# How do cast producers manage false bomb or artillery explosions?

Tags: film-techniques

As seen in *The Water Diviner*, the **Turkish troops** have made their final assault on the **ANZAC** troops who have actually slipped away from **Gallipoli**.

In movies like this, how do cast producers actually manage, use and make it look like the soldiers go flying from the explosion site of mines and artillery?

Also how do they make the explosions like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy bit first:

> how do they make the explosions like that?

They use explosives...

While the concussive force from an artillery shell is not entirely fun, most of the injury actually comes from the shrapnel of the shell or grenade casing rather than the explosion itself. Putting the explosive in a cardboard casing means it is mostly burnt up as part of the explosion.

That said - it still isn't all that safe (at a minimum, the air pressure of the concussive force can end up perforating eardrums - it can do worse depending on force and proximity). Also, by part burying the explosive in the ground, globs of soil, mud and other things can still be flung around.

> how do cast producers actually manage, use and make it look like the soldiers go flying from the explosion site of mines and artillery?

For one - they don't use anything like as much explosive as an actual shell would use. The point is to make it look good for the camera, not necessarily real.

Second, everyone on set will be given clear instructions on where the explosives will be set, and when they will be triggered - they may even use markers that are edited out of the shot. Someone off-camera will shout a warning before the explosive is detonated by wire.

Launching stuntmen into the air pretty low-tech - sometimes they just jump, other times they will be pulled by rope/pulley setups, or a spring-loaded pad will launch them onto a mattress that is out of shot.

In addition, these effects can be subsequently enhanced with computer editing techniques to give the impression that even more explosive was detonated than what was used on set.

And then, finally, there's just plain old simple editing to get it looking good for the cinema.

Comment: One of the techniques is to have one blast between the camera and the soldiers/stuntsmen, another one behind them. From the camera POV, when they go off simultaneously, we observe the soldiers in the middle of a big nice explosion. From another angle, you can see two separate blasts.

Comment: As to the 'flying soldiers' - they may use puppets for flying, combined with actor faces edited in. In the modern movies, they use CGI most likely.

Comment: @TimSparrow I didn't know about the two blast one, thanks. Don't know why I forgot to mention puppets.

Comment: Also worth mentioning - a carefully chosen camera angle can make it look like the actors are much closer to the explosion than they really are.  That combined with timed jumps or wires, as discussed above, brings the whole thing together without actually putting anyone in serious danger.